# User is auto signed out for no apparent reason

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We've tried just about everything and our users keep getting logged out from Google in our YouTube implementation for no apparent reason after about 30 mins.

Using the latest V3.

Comment: This happens every time you exit your Chrome browser?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I'm closing this, we were able to fix it.